# why does this power series converges to sinh(x)?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

given the infinite sum $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
of course, by ratio test, it converges for reals.
I know that the answer is $\sinh(x)$ and I've seen how this is derived from its taylor expansion. But how do you derive $\sinh(x)$ from this form?

Comment: Write $\sinh$ has the sum of known power series and simplify.

Comment: well I can indeed use sinh and write out its taylor expansion and end up with that sum, but I'm not so sure how I would reverse that process to start with the sum and end up with sinh.

Comment: Read it in the other direction?